# Properties of $I_{\mu}$ for Lagrangian Floer Homology in the Cotangent bundle

Tags: symplectic-topology, floer-homology

Following the notation of the book *"Lagrangian intersection Floer theory anomaly and obstruction"* suppose we have that our symplectic manifold is a cotangent bundle $T^*M$ with the canonical symplectic form and our two Lagrangian submanifolds are $L_0=\phi^1(T^*_{p}M)$ and $L_1=T_q^*M$ for some $p,q\in M$ and $\phi^t$ is a hamiltonian flow.

Now if we consider the equivalence relation that gives us the Novikov Covering where we have elements of the form $[l_p, \, w] $ and $[l_q, ' w']$, I am interested in seeing what happens to it. That is, consider the homomorphisms $I_{\omega}$ and $I_{\mu}$. It is easy to see that due to the fact the cotangent bundle is an exact symplectic manifold we will have that $I_{\omega}(C)=0$ for any $C=\bar w\# w'$ and so half of the equivalence relation is always true for any elements $[l_p,w]$ and $[l_p, \, w']$ that I consider. Now I am interested in seeing what happens with the other part of the equivalence relation.

> **Question.** Does anybody knows or has any suggestion on checking wether $I_{\mu}(C)=0$? Or more generally if our triple $(M, \, L_0,\,
> > L_1)$ will be monotone, i.e, if there exists a $\lambda >0$ such that
> $I_{\omega}=\lambda I_{\mu}$?

(I have tried to look for references but I could not find anything). Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
I found a formula in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07928.pdf relating the Maslov index of a complex vector bundle with the chern number plus an integral in the boundary . Maybe this can help but I was not able to get anything from it yet. We have that $I_{\mu}(C)=\int_{S^1\times I}C^*(c_1(TT^*M))+\int_{\partial(S^1\times I)}\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is discribed in the paper, but I am not seeing any good way to compute $\sigma$ or to see that it would be zero.